# How to keep a view always on top even there is push or present action

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to keep a view always on the top ,but I do not how to do .help me ,thanks!

Comment: if you want to keep a certain object on top even after push segue, then you need to look into ContainerView.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a UIWindow;

Comment: ```self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    UIView * topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
    topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    topView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
    [self.window addSubview:topView];```